# Including a particular view of users in a package

Tags: package, custom-view

On the Manage Users screen I create a new view which I find useful.  How do I include this view in a package? I don't see it in any of the options when I go to add components.

Answer (score 1):

You can now add user list views to a package. I have verified that this works in my developer edition organization. The component type is "list view", and the "type" column will contain the phrase "User". You can click on the Type column header, then click on "U" in the Rolodex to show all user list views.